# Rendering flash message only show after the first request, Laravel + Inertia + React + Vite

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, vite, inertiajs

BranchControler.php

```
public function add(AddBranchRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $branch = new Branch();
    $branch->name = $validated['name'];
    $branch->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'add success!']);
}

public function remove(RemoveBranchRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $branch = Branch::find($request->id);
    $branch->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'delete success']);
}
```

BranchView.jsx

```
const { flash } = usePage().props
```

I added this code to HandleInertiaRequests.php, following the instructions in the InertiaJS documentation

```
return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
    'flash' => [
        'success' => fn () => $request->session()->get('success')
    ]
]);
```

The problem is for the first time i'm requesting to the addController the flash message will be undefined, but after the second try the flash message contains the value from the previous request.

Scenario 1:

1. Request to add branch -> flash message was undefined
2. Request to add branch again -> flash message was not undefined (it use the previous flash message from the first request)

Scenario 2:

1. Request to add branch -> flash message was undefined
2. Request to delete branch -> flash message was not undefined (it use the previous flash message from the first request, so it show the 'add success' not 'delete success')

I don't understand why this is happening. When I make the first request after refreshing the page, the flash message is always undefined. However, for the subsequent requests, the flash message always displays the previous message from the previous request. Is this happening because I'm using 'redirect back,' or did I overlook something?